# Cannot enable regular expression global flag in NodeJS REPL due to autocomplete

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I want to write regular expression with global flag in NodeJS REPL like this

`/abc/g`

However I cannot add to `g` flag due to code autocomplete

When typing above code to RPEL, firstly, it displays a shadow of word `global` like this

[image: 1]

Then after pressing `Enter` it replaces the `g` flag with word `global` and throws an error

[image: 2]

How can I use `g` flag without autocomplete replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the autocomplete by adding a "space" ( ) after flag `g`.

```js
const a = /abc/g 
                ^--- space here
```

[image]